# Is it possible to find the integral of ${\rm Re}(x)$ or ${\rm Im}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, complex-integration

I was just wondering, if it was possible to evaluate the following integrals:

$\int_{C} {\rm Re}(x) \,{\rm d}x$

$\int_{C} {\rm Im}(x) \,{\rm d}x$

Where ${\rm Re}(x) $gives the real part of a complex number and ${\rm Im}(x)$ gives the imaginary part, and $C$ is a unit circle centered at the origin of a complex plane. I am new to complex integrations, so it would be much appreciated if you could break down advanced concepts, if used. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Parametrize the unit circle. That’s your first step. Second step: recall how a line integral is defined. Third step: use the definition. Fourth step: calculate the resulting single-variable integral.